# How can I inspect/audit an Android phone if it's vulnerable to CVE-2012-4221 (or any other?)

Tags: mobile, android, patching

I want to create a guide (or app) to audit devices and determine if the hardware or software is vulnerable to attack.

Given an arbitrary phone, what process should I do to determine if outstanding patches / vulnerabilities exist?

Or asked a slightly different way, are all the patches exclusive to Google, or are there 3rd party drivers must I inspect?

Comment: You may also want to look at [Android Vulnerability Test Suite](https://github.com/nowsecure/android-vts)

Comment: Do you have any input over the devices you may be required to audit? A limited vendor list will probably make this task a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple facets to this question.

1. Phone vendors will typically push patches at their leisure. So part of the question becomes "who is your software vendor?" and "are you running a stock image?" This will determine if there is updated software available.
2. If in doubt, you can collect proof of concept testers on the internet to attack mobile phones with. This is spotty at best, because not every vulnerability lends itself well to packaging as a risk-free auto-pwn site. The Android Vulnerability Suite that WoJ linked will be helpful with this.
3. If you are looking at Android as a ecosystem, you'll need to tangle with app permissions and app updates. Apps can introduce vulnerabilities as well, and occasionally updates cannot be done (I've had this happen due to picture overload).
4. For hardware, it will be a little more esoteric. You'll have to pull in information from the internet about handsets and compile that into your guide. Luckily for your guide (and unluckily for your users), hardware exploits are harder to fix in production, so it should turn into a simple comparison once you find a reputable source.